# Modifying a legend in javascript

Tags: javascript, list

I basically need the legend to look like/say this: 
80+ (or80%+) 
75-80
70-75
65-70
60-65
55-50
<50%

I have the list in descending order and the everything is good except I can't get the less than symbol to work properly.

The code is

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

    legend.onAdd = function (map) {

        var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
            grades = [80, 75,70, 65, 60, 55, 50,],
            labels = [],
            from, to;

        for (var i =0; i < grades.length; i++) {
            from = grades[i-1];
            to = grades[i];

            labels.push(
                '<i style="background:' + getColor(to + 1) + '"></i> ' +
                to  + (from ?'&ndash;' + from : '+'));
        }

        div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
        return div;
    };

    legend.addTo(map);
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: What is `L`? Is it some kind of library?

Comment: are you talking about the `&lt;` sign ( < ) ?

Comment: I believe the L may be from a library since I did download this and I have just been putting in the < sign and not a code, so maybe that's the problem. I will try it now.

Comment: tried putting in the code and it didn't work. I am unexperienced so it may be that I'm not putting it in the right place or correctly.

Comment: Your `for` loop is going to stop after `50-55`. After the loop, you would need to add something like this: `labels.push('<i style="background:' + getColor(50 + 1) + '"></i> %lt;50');` … But all this code is incredibly over-engineered for what it's trying to accomplish anyway. See my answer below.

Comment: Answering my own comment from earlier: Looks like `L` is for [leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com), which is a framework for manipulating maps (like street maps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have no idea what `L` is but I get the general idea of what you're doing.

something like

> 80+
>
> 80 - 75
>
> ...
>
> 55 - 50
>
> <50

The thing is you need to check for the 3 scenarios.

> Only to (80+)
>
> both to and from (80 - 50)
>
> only from (<50)

All you should have to do is change this

```
 for (var i =0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        from = grades[i-1];
        to = grades[i];

        labels.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(to + 1) + '"></i> ' +
            to  + (from ?'&ndash;' + from : '+'));
    }
```

To

```
for (var i =0; i <= grades.length; i++) {
        /*don't cause an array out of bounds problem*/
        from = (i-1>-1)?grades[i-1]:0;
        to = (i < grades.length)?grades[i]:0;

        labels.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(to + 1) + '"></i> ' +
             (/*Check to for a value*/to ? to : '&lt;') +
             ((/*Check both to and from for a value*/to&&from)?'&ndash;':'') + 
             (/*Check from for a value*/from  ? from + 
                 (/*check to for a value after knowing from has a value*/ to ? '': '%'): '%+'));
    }
```

Comment: The `to` variable will always be defined because it's the current index of the `grades` array that we're looping through. However, this would work if you add `0` to the end of the grades array since `0` is a falsy value.

Comment: @aapierce are you sure? I'm not 100% on what's returned on an array out of bounds request but apparently when they read `grades[-1]` they're getting 0 I assumed that `grade[LENGTH]` would do the same. But maybe its just that it was defaulted to 0 and never changed it's value. I'll tweak my answer to reset the values to 0 each time.

Comment: @aapierce I see what you meant now. I fixed my answer but yeah this is over kill if all they wanted was what you wrote in you're answer.

Comment: Dan you are brilliant! do you know how to add a percentage sign after <50% and (maybe) after 80?

Comment: if you change the loop from `i < grades.length` to `i <= grades.length`, I suppose that would work too, since it runs one-too-many times (so to speak). Although doing it this way is a little too unclear for my taste.

Comment: @user3407952 check my update. This isn't really pretty code but it's what you asked for.

Comment: I also just cleaned up the `to` and `from` assignment to not cause an array out of bounds look up. Javascript might handle that ok but most languages would not be so forgiving. Best practice is to not cause those.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in creating HTML markup for the legend, and the legend data never changes, why not keep it simple?

```
legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
    div.innerHTML = "<i style='background:green'>80+</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:green'>75-80</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:yellow'>70-75</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:yellow'>65-70</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:red'>60-65</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:red'>55-60</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:red'>50-55</i><br />"+
        "<i style='background:red'>&lt;50</i>";

    return div;
}
```

Obviously, you might want to tweak your colors a little, but this way it's *far* more easier to understand. There's no reason to go out of your way to generate a small amount of static markup.